# loading long webview over 500kb

Tags: android, webview, load

I have a webview and an string that holds over 500kb which displays the page. Does anyone have any idea to decrease the loading time of a webview?. The way I load is synchronous would it be better if I load it asynchronous. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to increase loading time?

Comment: And I assume your string is the html markup

Comment: Sorry I meant decrease loading time.

Comment: @whatsthebeef yes it is at html markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to **increase** the loading time of your web view while other views load normally you should

1. Create a asynctask passing it the web view object
2. Put a `Thread.sleep(<time you want to wait>)` in it set at how long you would like to wait, then execute `loadData(<data>)`
3. When you are loading your views call `execute` on your async tasks and it will perform the sleep then load in the background while other views are being populated.

Is that really what you want to do?

**UPDATED**

You can't decrease the time it takes to load the web view by loading it asynchronous but you can stop it from blocking other views from loading while it loads.

If the page makes sense (doesn't look a mess) without the web view then you can load it on a separate thread (`AsyncTask` or creating a runnable class and calling `runOnUiThread()`) task with that view being updated when it is ready. An option would be to load from a thread and make the thread low priority so it would most likely wait for views to be rendered and then start the heavy html processing.

You could also look at splitting the html up into separate views, embedding the dynamic content in standard android views or launching the browser activity and displaying it there

Comment: Sorry I meant decrease loading time. I made a typo.

Comment: I do appreciate your quick answer.

Comment: What I am trying right now is doing a synchronize threading on a 5 different webviews which each gets prioritize from 1 to the 5th webview. Of course I have to connect them but this way it should display the first webview and once its finish it goes to the next webview and so on. Right now I am stuck trying to figure out an event handler to combine the webviews together which I was thinking scrolling at end of webview. I can't seem to find the overwrite functionality for such an event on android developer website yet. Still looking.

Comment: @Akyl lite, I don't fully understand but would be happy to help out if you provide more details, can you create a new question with a bit more info and I will try answer it

Comment: here you go I added a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493141/synchronizing-and-combining-webviews-together-to-reduce-loading-for-files-over-5